# Can I travel from Saudi Arabia to Pakistan and back with a passport due to expire in less than 3 months?

Tags: passports, pakistan, saudi-arabia

I am working in Saudi Arabia and I have planned to travel to Pakistan for a month, starting on 20 November 2019.  My passport will expire on 15 January 2020. Can I make this trip without any passport issues arising?

Comment: What country passport do you hold?

Answer (score 2):

You will have no issues entering Pakistan and, assuming you're a resident of Saudi-Arabia and not a US citizen, you will have no issues returning to Saudi-Arabia either.

According to Timatic, the rules are as follows:

> #### Pakistan (PK)
>
> Document Validity:
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be **valid on arrival**.
>
> #### Saudi Arabia (SA)
>
> Document Validity:
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
> - Passports issued to nationals of the USA must be valid for the period of intended stay.
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to nationals of Saudi Arabia must be valid on arrival.
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to **residents of Saudi Arabia** must be **valid on arrival**.